# Pull email address from appSettings

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I'm trying to pull an email address from the appSettings section of the app.config file.  Every time I run a test, reportRecipients is Null.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Overdue_Report_Recipients" value="myemail@email.com"/>
  </appSettings>

string reportRecipients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Overdue_Report_Recipients"];
```

Thanks

**Edit:**
this is for a project that is not a web app. It's part of a Solution where most of the projects are web apps but this particular one is a service.  sorry for the confusion with asp.net tag i have removed it.

I have another value stored in app Settings and I'm able to get the data from it

```
<add key="Sweeper_Notify_When_None_Overdue" value="false"/> 

bool sendWhenNoneOverdue = 
                Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sweeper_Notify_When_None_Overdue"]);
```

**ANSWER:
I was running my test in a separate project and the test was reading from the config file in the test project and not the app.config in the project I was testing.
I had to copy the settings to the config in the test project and then the test worked.**

Comment: You have this in your web.config, right?  Under "configuration" -> "configSections" ???

Comment: @Zachary, I agree I think Ronald might not have the <configuration> element.

Comment: What do you get if you use index 0 instead of the key?

Comment: Its possible to specify in web.config which file to use like: <appSettings file="FILENAME.config"></appSettings>

Comment: its in the App.Config not web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running my test in a separate project and the test was reading from the config file in the test project and not the app.config in the project I was testing. I had to copy the settings to the config in the test project and then the test worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using ASP.NET, the `<appSettings>` section should be within the `web.config` file, not `app.config` as you describe.

When you call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["some key"]` from within your `asp.net` website or web application it is going to look in the `web.config` file. If you've stored your key in the app.config file that is why it comes back null.

You can alternatively store your app settings in a separate file from web.config if you prefer. To do so, in your web.config put:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="someSettingsFile.config" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

Then in someSettingsFile.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Overdue_Report_Recipients" value="myemail@email.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

I suspect however you just misplaced the location of `appSettings` in the wrong file. Just move it to your `web.config` and you should be fine.

Comment: is there a way to do this using the app.config file?

Comment: you could try referencing the app.config file as the external reference for the `appSettings` section like in your web.config `<appSettings file="app.settings"/>` but I'm not sure of the ramifications. Should work I assume. ASP.NET will ALWAYS look in the web.config first so the `file=""` attribute is a must if you want to use a separate file for the section.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reportRecipients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Overdue_Report_Recipients"].ToString();
```

Update.

I just noted in my own code that there is no need for the .ToString() and what you have there should work fine.

Just to confirm, web.config should be similiar to;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Overdue_Report_Recipients" value="myemail@email.com"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The OP noted the use of app.Settings file, but should be using web.config for an ASP.NET project. I've noted this in my answer.